# The mysqli error was: Unknown database

Tags: mysql, drupal

I am importing a mysql database from the webserver to my local system for a migration from drupal 6 to drupal 8.

I did an Export with phpmyadmin on the server. Then I created the database locally also with phpmyadmin and imported my dump from the server via phpmyadmin's import function.
Then I created the user with the setting of my drupal 6 configuration.

I can see the database in phpmyadmin if I connect with my local root user. 
I cannot connect with the user created from the settings ( lets call that the drupal_db_user)
If I call the drupal site on my local apache ( apache & mysql server are running or my phpmyadmin would not work) I get the messeage from drupal:
"The mysqli error was: Unknown database 'my_drupal_db'."

Via Mysqlworkbench I am also not able to conntect to the my_drupal_db with the  drupal_db_user.

I use locally php 5.6 and mysql 5.6 on a ubuntu system.

Creating the user and db via mysql console also did not help.

Any clue what might be wrong here? I suspect it could be the password encryption, but I have no clue how to check / change that other than trying the two options phpmyadmin (version 4.6) is offering me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem.
after at least 3 hours poking around and cursing.....
When I created the database locally I had by mistake an whitespace in front of the db name.

Which by the way was possible... I didn't know you could even create databases with whitespaces in the name.

What let me find the error was this post:
https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/27050/fatal-error-pdoexception-sqlstate42000-1049-unknown-database
and the hint with this query:

```
SELECT * FROM my_drupal_db.users
```

which of course failed and made me really question the database name.

Hope that helps someone else saving 3 hours!

Answer (score 0):

I guess you dont need to backup on your pc as the files that you exported from server is a backup on its own. Just download the sql file update to drupal 8 and finally import the file and you should have it installed.

Or simply try importing the exported file from server to another subdomain drupal 8 as a test. To check If it really works.

Comment: https://www.drupal.org/node/2350603
States that you should do the upgrade definetly NOT online.
So what I am trying to do is get the drupal 6 running on my local machine to do the upgrade there. 
But without access to the db, there won't be an upgrade, since no running drupal 6 system.
And I guess the problem here is not drupal, but some error in my way to create & import the db with this user.